# Jquery remove element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am basically trying to print the value of a button in the div with list class if the button is selected. Also remove the same value wwhen it is deselected. I am able to print the value successfully but not able to remove it. Could somebody please help me out with it.

```
var buttonSelect = $(".btn").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(".list").append(this.value + "   ")
    }
    else {
        $(".list").remove(this.value)
    }
});
```

Comment: `this` is the HTML element, and `$(this)` is the jQuery object. Try to use `$(".list").remove($(this))`

Comment: $(this) would remove the whole button aint it? It would select the object i suppose

Comment: Yes, because `remove()` removes an object, if you just want to clear the text you can do `$(this).text("")` or any of the answers listed below

Comment: `jquery.remove()` removes **elements** from the DOM, a **TextNode** is not an **element**.. however, both are "**objects**".. so I would refrain from using **object** as some sort of qualifier here..

Comment: here.. this is the distinction.. **nodeType** http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodetype.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather append the content along with html element like span:

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
     $(".list").append('<span class="newval_'+this.value+'">'+this.value + "</span>");
}else{ 
     $(".list").find('.newval_'+this.value).remove();
}});
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) Worked perfect! However i dont understand the need to use the span element. Would be indebted if you could tell me the concept.

Comment: What append is doing is creating a text object and sticking it on the end. It's not a string manipulator, it's a DOM manipulator. In order to have something to remove later, you need to have an object in the DOM to remove and a text object won't work. This code adds a span object to the page as the very last thing inside `.list` and then removes the span object when the button is pressed again. Hope that helps!

Comment: Clear now! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The parameters from `.remove()` is a selector, just having a value in there that contains the content of the element you want to remove will not work. For example if I had this:

```
<li class="list">test</li>
```

Doing `$(".list").remove("test")` will not remove it. You will probably want to use the `:contains` selector (since you may have the value with spaces at the end). So in the example above doing `$(".list").remove(":contains('test')")` will remove the element. You can do the same thing in your case:

```
$(".list").remove(":contains('"+this.value+"')");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the element itself along with everything in it, just use jQuery’s [remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("div").remove();  //remove Div element
    });
});
```

You can see an example here: [How to Remove Elements from DOM in jQuery](https://stackhowto.com/how-to-remove-elements-from-dom-in-jquery/)